# Angularjs: how to pass scope variables to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

I am trying to use directive to create and append several tags to a `<div>` as shown below:

```
module.directive('createControl', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){    
    console.log(attrs.createControl); // undefined     
  }                                          
});                                         


<div class="control-group" ng-repeat="(k, v) in selectedControls">
  <div create-control="{{ v.type }}"></div>
</div>
```

In attrs I have this construction:

```
$$element: b.fn.b.init[1]
$$observers: Object
$attr: Object
createControl: "date"
style: "margin-right: 15px"
__proto__: Object
```

But when I try to use `attrs.createControl` I get `undefined` and I do not understand why. Actual question: how to pass scope variable to a directive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read **Attributes/observing interpolated attributes** section of the [**directive docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). During the link phase the attributes haven't been set.

There are several ways including using `attrs.$observe` or `$timeout`.

```
app.directive('createControl', function($timeout){
 return function(scope, element, attrs){
      attrs.$observe('createControl',function(){
        console.log(' type:',attrs.createControl);
         element.text('Directive text, type is: '+attrs.createControl);
      });
  }
}) ;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZablzwh0EGv285LveMZ?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 34):

```
    app.directive('createControl', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          createControl:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){    
           element.text(scope.createControl);    
        }      
      }
    })  

  <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="v in [{type:'green'}, {type:'brown'}]">
    <div create-control="v.type"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Not so sure I get this one, how does it now the div is the directive?

Comment: Jackie, Angular looks for a directive (camelCase) that matches the `create-control` (hyphenated lower-case) attribute.

Comment: explanations, will hopefully help someone else: 1.) `'@'` will not work, for whatever reason. 2.) can also be applied using multiple variables, like `<create-control val1="v.type" value-two="x.y"></create-control>`. Note that `value-two` also becomes camelCase in the directive scope definition (`valueTwo`). 3.) there must be no `{{}}` around the variable (such as, NO `...="{{v.type}}"`)

Answer (score 15):

If `v.type` may change (i.e., you really need to use interpolation -- the {{}}s), use @charlietfl's or @Joe's answser, depending on the type of scope you want your directive to have.

If `v.type` will not change (i.e., your link function only needs to get the values once, and those values are guaranteed to be set when your link function runs), you can use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) or [$eval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval) instead.  This has a slight performance advantage in that no $watches are created.  (With `$observe()` and `=`, Angular sets up $watches, which are evaluated every digest cycle.)

```
<div create-control="v.type"></div>
```

```js
app.directive('createControl', function ($parse) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('$eval type:', scope.$eval(attrs.createControl));
        var type = $parse(attrs.createControl)(scope);
        console.log('$parse type:', type);
        element.text('Directive text, type is: ' + type);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/25hPT/)</kbd>